# Jenkins - API to update build status

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build my project. When the build is ready, the product is downloaded and tested. I would like to notify Jenkins that the build is tested and then to notify it about the test results. I would like that once jenkis has created the build, it is available to download, but that there is a message like 'build is tested' or 'tests passed/failed'. 
Uploading a file with this kind of information would be OK as well.

Is it possible with jenkins?

I do not want to integrate my tests into jenkins build process: they take too long and use too much resources (and must be carried out on a separate machine with dedicated environment)

Comment: Jenkins can run its jobs on "slaves" too. You can configure Jenkins to run your tests on the exact machine you run them manually right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup 2 promotions on the build job. Call one "Tests Passed" and another "Tests Failed".

The promotions will add different colored "star" icons to the individual builds to indicate which promotions had been executed. All build artifact downloads and other build information is available regardless of promotion status.

If you will be "notifying" Jenkins manually, you just need to manually execute a promotion. You can also access a permalink to the last successful promoted build's artifacts like `http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/[PROMOTION_NAME]/artifact`

If you want your test process to notify Jenkins automatically, you would need to trigger it by sending a call to the webpage. You can use CURL to request `http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/[JOB_NUMBER]/Promotion/[PROMOTION_NAME]/build`. Of course you need to know the number of the build that you are trying to mark for promotion. Alternatively, you can use the "Last Successful" permalink like `http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/promotion/[PROMOTION_NAME]/build`

Comment: I've created the two promotions, tried to force one of them (manually, through jenkins web interface), but for some reason the build got both stars: somehow the second promotion was applied automatically. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Also, the "Approve" button can only be clicked once, but you can use "Force Promotion" button to run it multiple times (if you have permissions)